# counting no. Of days categorized in months

Tags: php

counting no. Of days between two dates inclusive of starting date is easy but how to count them saperately for each months like between 1.1.2014 and 15.5.2014

```
Jan 31
Feb 28
Mar 31
Apr 30
May 15
```

Comment: @Dagon the second answer of that question is more relevant to this question that the accepted answer

Comment: i just reformatted the question it's different now :-)

Comment: You do that per each month in that period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$start = new DateTime('2014-01-01');
$end = new DateTime('2014-05-15');

$tmpStart = $start;
while ( $tmpStart <= $end ) {
    $tmpEnd = clone $tmpStart;
    $tmpEnd = $tmpEnd->modify('last day of this month');
    $tmpEnd = $tmpEnd < $end ? $tmpEnd : clone $end;
    echo $tmpStart->format("M") . " " . ($tmpEnd->diff($tmpStart)->format("%a")+1) . "\n";
    $tmpStart = $tmpEnd->modify('first day of next month');
}
```

This outputs:

```
Jan 31 
Feb 28 
Mar 31 
Apr 30 
May 15
```

Answer (score 0):

get the number of days in month from [cal_days_in_month()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) function and use [date_diff()](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)  to compare between those

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to find the difference in days between two dates?

```
<?php
$startDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1970); //Enter your start date and time
$endDate = mktime(0, 0, 0, 5, 20, 2014); //Enter your end date and time

echo ($endDate-$startDate)/60/60/24; //This works out the number of days between the two
?>
```

Outputs:

```
16210
```

Look at the [mktime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) documentation to understand how to input your date into the `mktime()` function.

Comment: that's not exactly what he wants